# how to attach event to control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding dropdown list control dynamically in my form on button click event and on change event of the added dropdown list based on datatype want to bind/attach the onkeypress event to the textbox. For that, I am using below code but it’s not working.

```
$("#txtDefaultValue_" + id).bind("onkeypress", "return isNumber(event)")
```

So please let me know how can attach or bind the event to control.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** I didn’t notice before, but the event should be `keypress` not `onkeypress`.

---

The second parameter to [`.bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) should be a function, not a string:

```js
$("#txtDefaultValue" + id).bind("keypress", function(event) {
  return isNumber(event);
});
```

Or more succinctly:

```js
$("#txtDefaultValue" + id).bind("keypress", event => isNumber(event));
```

It should be noted, however, that `.bind()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 3.0 (although its use was discouraged since 1.7). Instead you should be using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), which in your simple case has the same call signature:

```js
$("#txtDefaultValue" + id).on("keypress", event => isNumber(event));
```

Comment: I am using below function on dropdown change event and in that, I have bind the event but it's not working.
function BindEvent(id)
    {
            var dataType = $("#ddlDataType_" + id + "").val();
            if(dataType=='INTEGER'){
                    $("#txtDefaultValue" + id).bind("onkeypress", function (event)
                    {
                        return isNumber(event);
                    });
                    }
            }
    }

Comment: What does “*not working*” mean? What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens? Have you determined where the problem occurs?

Comment: onkeypress not firing when i enter something into textbox.

Comment: If you add `console.log('onkeypress', event);` just before `return isNumber...`, do you see anything appear in the console?

Comment: Nothing appear in console.

Comment: Are you still using `bind` or have you changed to `on` as I suggested originally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183815/discussion-between-mtcoster-and-pankaj).